# What are Basis images?

Tags: fourier-analysis, transformation, education, signal-processing, image-processing

I have read that using Fourier transformation we can decompose any arbitrary image into orthogonal basis images and reconstruct it back.

But what are basis images actually?

Comment: The definition of orthogonal and examples thereof are easily found in a few seconds with a search engine. A basis image is just like a basis vector except that it's a 2-D array.

Answer (score 2):

The JPEG format is based on the Discrete Cosine Transform, a real form of the Fourier transform.

You can also use SVD to compress images. See this [Wolfram demonstrations](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ImageCompressionViaTheSingularValueDecomposition/) for instance.